# How to convert into a definite integral

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

Could you show me how to convert the following into a definite integral:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{3n} \frac{1}{n}\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's literally

$$\int_0^3\cos(\pi x)\sin(2\pi x)dx$$

The substitution $u=\pi x$ re-expresses it as

$${1\over\pi}\int_0^{3\pi}\cos(u)\sin(2u)du$$

The basic idea is to think of the $1\over n$ as $\Delta x$, which in the limit becomes a $dx$, and $k/n$ as $x$, which in the limit varies from $0$ when $k=1$ to $3$ when $k=3n$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have one question though, what justified us to take 1/n as delta x? I'm sorry my understanding is patchy.

Comment: I'm glad to see you don't just want to know what the answer is, you also want to *understand* it.  The idea is that you're sampling the function at $x_1=1/n$, $x_2=2/n$, up to $x_{3n}=3n/n$.  In doing a Riemann sum, $\Delta x$ is the (horizontal) width of the skinny rectangular approximation for the area of a vertical slice, so in this case is $x_k-x_{k-1}=k/n-(k-1)/n=1/n$.

Comment: Thank you very much for that comprehensive answer sir!

Answer (score 6):

Recall the Riemann sum $$\int_{x=a}^b f(x) \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n f\left(a + \frac{b-a}{n} k\right) \frac{b-a}{n}.$$  Write your limit as $$S = \lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{3m} \frac{1}{m} \cos \frac{k\pi}{m} \sin \frac{2k\pi}{m}.$$  Then with the choice $n = 3m$, $a = 0$, $b = 1$, $f(x) = \cos 3\pi x \sin 6\pi x,$ we get $$S = 3 \int_{x=0}^1 \cos 3\pi x \sin 6\pi x \, dx = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{x=0}^{3\pi} \cos x \sin 2x \, dx.$$